# Dicionario Python

Tags: python, dicionário

Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou tendo muita dificuldade em fazer esse exercicio.

Considere o seguinte conjunto de dados: Nome + (N1, N2, N3, N4). Nome representa
o nome de um aluno e deve ser usado como chave. Já N1, N2, N3, N4 representam as
notas de provas desse aluno. Utilize uma estrutura de dicionário com listas para resolver
este exercício.
Escreva um programa que leia os dados de N alunos e apresente na tela se foram
aprovados ou reprovados. O critério que garante a aprovação é que a média aritmética das
4 notas seja maior ou igual 7,0. O valor de N é a quantidade de alunos, e esse valor deve
ser lido do teclado no começo do programa. Faça um laço de repetição para a leitura destes
N alunos. As notas devem ser exibidas ao final do programa com uma casa decimal de
precisão.

Este foi o código que estou fazendo.

```py
n = int(input('Quantos alunos?  '))
nome = {}
notas = []
i = 0
while i < n:
    nome['Aluno'] = str(input('Nome do aluno: ')).capitalize().strip()
    n1 = float(input('1ª nota:  '))
    notas.append(n1)

    n2 = float(input('2ª nota:  '))
    notas.append(n2)

    n3 = float(input('3ª nota:  '))
    notas.append(n3)

    n4 = float(input('4ª nota:  '))
    notas.append(n4)

    nome['Notas'] = notas

    media = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4
    if media >= 7:
        nome['status'] = 'Aprovado'
    else:
        nome['status'] = 'Reprovado'

    i += 1

    continue
for i in nome['Notas']:
    for j, k, l in nome.values():
        print('{} {} {} '.format(nome['Aluno'],nome['Notas'],nome['status'], end=''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, basicamente o problema é que você usa o mesmo dicionário e a mesma lista para armazenar as informações de todos os alunos e isso se perde no meio do seu código.

No enunciado é bem claro que o nome do aluno deve servir como chave do dicionário: "*Nome representa o nome de um aluno e **deve ser usado como chave***", mas você definiu duas chaves, `Aluno` e `Notas`.

Então, basicamente falta seguir o que o enunciado pede:

```py
N = int(input('Quantos alunos? '))

students = {}

for i in range(1, N+1):
  name = input(f'Nome do aluno {i}: ')
  grades = []

  for j in range(1, 5):
    grade = float(input(f'Nota {j} do aluno {i}: '))
    grades.append(grade)

  students[name] = grades

for name, grades in students.items():
  average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
  result = 'aprovado' if average >= 7.0 else 'reprovado'
  print(f'O aluno {name} foi {result} com média {average:.1f}')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, entendi onde errei. Deus te abençoe